# Can an ampersand (&) be used in SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server

With SQL Server, does the ampersand pose as a threat related to SQL injection? I'm working on a project that includes this as a blacklisted character. I'm aware that there's a threat related to Oracle (SQL*Plus) but cannot seem to find an issue with the ampersand. I've referenced multiple cheat sheets and articles, and cannot find a reference to it (other than Oracle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes, but no more so than any other T-SQL syntax.  The & is used for bitwise actions, and if there is an applicable SQL injection vulnerability found, an attacker could use it to probe for more information about the structure of the query/data, but it's a very specialized scenario, and, in my opinion, a very low priority.  I can think of many more reasons to whitelist an ampersand than I can to blacklist it.

See the link below for more documentation about the operator.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score -4):

You can do the following:

You have to replace the `'` by `Chr(146)`.  For example, in vb.net you can use `string.Replace("'", Chr(146))`.

SQL accepts `chr(146)`, but not the `chr(39)`.

Comment: How is this answer related to the question?